# IOS Setting Viewcontroller property bad access error

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, nsdate

I am trying to set the property of a child view controller (DateViewController) from the parent and getting a bad access error the second time I do so.  Here is the code.  This is the DateViewController.h.  The problem lies with the selectedDate property:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol DateViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) dateViewControllerDismissed:(NSDate *)selectedDate;
@end

@interface DateViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateReceipt;
    id myDelegate;
}

-(IBAction)btnDone;
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSDate *selectedDate;
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<DateViewDelegate> myDelegate;
@end
```

Inside DateViewController.m, I do synthesize selectedDate.  Now in the parent view controller (ComdataIOSViewController.m) I set the selectedDate property of the DateViewController to the variable receiptDate which is declared as an NSDate * in the @interface section of ComdataIOSViewController.h.  This is a snippet of ComdataIOSViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    receiptDate = [NSDate date];
}

-(IBAction)btnSetDate {
    dlgDate=[[DateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    dlgDate.selectedDate = receiptDate;
    dlgDate.myDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:dlgDate animated:true];
    [dlgDate release];
}

-(void) dateViewControllerDismissed:(NSDate *)selectedDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    receiptDate = selectedDate;
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:receiptDate];
    lblDate.text = dateString;
}
```

So the first time I click the set date button on the parent controller, the DateViewController appears, I pick the date from the datepicker control, and the controller is dismissed.  In the parent view controller, dateViewControllerDismissed gets called and I set the receiptDate to the selectedDate parameter.  The next time I click the date button, I get a bad access error where I set the DateViewController's selectedDate property to the receiptDate.  I'm assuming this is some sort of memory issue that I'm not handling correctly.  IOS programming is still new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several problems in your code which could lead your application to crash. Actually they are memory management problem.

1. Assigning autoreleased object to `receiptDate`:

   ```
   receiptDate = [NSDate date];
   ```

   when you will try to use this value later it will cause app crash because memory where `receiptDate` point could be already released. You could fix it by retaining the value:

   ```
   receiptDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
   ```

   and releasing in `dealloc` or anywhere you are changing it (I dont know how it is declared. It should be `retain` property).
2. You are assigning `NSDate` without retaining it:

   ```
   receiptDate = selectedDate;
   ```

   you could fix it by retaining:

   ```
   receiptDate = [selectedDate retain];
   ```

I am sorry because I could not write all aspects of memory management in objective-C. It is better to use ARC if you don't know iOS memory managent well.

You could find a lot of useful information in this two guides from Apple: [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your property is never retained. What I would suggest to do would be to change the `assign` to `retain` in your property declaration. That'll solve your problem and you won't have to call `retain` everywhere you set selectedDate. The property will do that for you.

If you're not using ARC, don't forget to set the property to nil in your dealloc method, like so:

```
self.selectedDate = nil;
```

Note that I use self.selectedDate. It's important so that selectedDate is accessed as a property, not a variable.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I previously did have the property set to retain and it didn't make any difference (even though you are correct - it should be set to retain).  The answer below fixed my problem.

Comment: Glad you fixed your problem. :)